# Magento Search Form Mini Repeat Disfunction

Tags: ajax, forms, magento, search

In my website, I have two menu top bars. One stay's in the header section and other shows up only when the user has arrived certain point of the scroll (I used a simple jQuery code here). The problem here is that both the top bars has included in it the Search Form Mini, but only in the first one that is rendered (in my case, the '#hiddenMenu' topbar) the ajax live search works.

Just for you to understand, the **header.phtml** file:

```
<div id="hiddenMenu">
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topMenu') ?>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topBar') ?>
</div>
<div class="header-container">
<div class="quick-access">
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topLinks') ?>
</div>

<div class="header">
    <?php if ($this->getIsHomePage()):?>
    <h1 class="logo"><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" class="logo"><img src="<?php echo $this->getLogoSrc() ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" /></a></h1>
    <?php else:?>
    <h1 class="logo"><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" class="logo"><img src="<?php echo $this->getLogoSrc() ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" /></a>
    <?php endif?></h1>
</div>

<div id="menu">
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topMenu') ?>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topBar') ?>
</div>

<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topContainer'); ?>
```

As you can see, the only difference between the two of them, is where they are placed, because the search.mini.form is called by **getChildHtml('topBar')**. But in the second appearence of the search.mini.form, for some reason, the ajax live search does not work.

My **form.mini.phtml** file stills the original:

```
<?php $catalogSearchHelper =  $this->helper('catalogsearch'); ?>
<form id="search_mini_form" action="<?php echo $catalogSearchHelper->getResultUrl() ?>" method="get">
   <div class="form-search">
        <div class="search-mini">
            <input id="search" placeholder="Busque" type="text" name="<?php echo $catalogSearchHelper->getQueryParamName() ?>" class="input-text" />
            <button type="submit" title="<?php echo $this->__('Go') ?>" class="button"><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/ico-search.png') ?>"></button>   
        </div>
        <div id="search_autocomplete" class="search-autocomplete"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
           //<![CDATA[
               var searchForm = new Varien.searchForm('search_mini_form', 'search', 'Search');
               searchForm.initAutocomplete('<?php echo $catalogSearchHelper->getSuggestUrl() ?>', 'search_autocomplete');
           //]]>
        </script>
    </div>
</form>
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Your two search forms have the same name.

When you call :

new Varien.searchForm('search_mini_form'

it refers only to the first one, and then you attach the Live Search Ajax thing to this one.

Only this one.

You should have 2 different names, and set Ajax thing to both forms.

REgards

Comment: Thanks for the help, but setting different names for the forms havent solved the problem. Right now, I'm trying set them different Ajax Events too. See what happens.

Comment: Dagfr, although only changing the name of the forms havent solved my problem, it was in the way. I have to change also the input name, and the auto complete id. I only added a whatever sufix ('_hidden' in this case. And it worked. I also had to assure the concordance on the Ajax call: var searchForm = new Varien.searchForm('search_menu_hidden', 'search_hidden', '');searchForm.initAutocomplete('<?php echo $catalogSearchHelper->getSuggestUrl() ?>', 'search_autocomplete_hidden');